# The following code shouldn't work, yet it does?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement, particle-system

This code makes no sense to me, it's probably stupid mistake on my side. But if someone could explain the error I made, that would be great.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Tower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform objectToPan = default;
    [SerializeField] Transform enemyTarget = default;
 
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem BulletParticles = default;
    [SerializeField] EnemyDamage StopIfDead = default; //Another Script
 
    bool isNotDead = true;
 
    const int maxShootRange = 30;
 
    void Update()
    {
        TowerShoots();
    }
 
    void TowerShoots()
    {
        float distanceBetweenBoth = Vector3.Distance(objectToPan.transform.position, enemyTarget.transform.position);
        if (distanceBetweenBoth >= maxShootRange)
        {
            BulletParticles.Play();            
        }
        if (StopIfDead.isDead == true)
        {
            WhenDead();
        }
    }
 
    void WhenDead()
    {
        const int DeathRota = 0;
        isNotDead = false;
        BulletParticles.Stop();
        objectToPan.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(DeathRota, DeathRota, DeathRota);
    }
}
```

First major thing I noticed is that

```
if(distanceBetweenBoth >= maxShootRange)
{
    //Stuff
}
```

Doesn't this mean that, *if* the distance is greater, or equal to, than play the particles. The problem  is that, if the distance is greater than the maxShootRange (30), than it won't shoot above 30. The problem is that if the distance between these two object is greater than, or equal to, the maxShootRange (30), than it won't shoot something that is further than maxShootRange. It actually shoots under the 30 and below. I have tried many different type of ways, non of which seem to work. I tried to switch the order of objectToPan with enemyTarget. Yet it basically does the same thing. If I make an else statement saying not to shoot. Than the code completely stops shooting. I tried to turn on and off PlayOnAwake and see what effect that had. But now I am not sure.

```
else
{
    //Stop the Bullets
}
```

If you need more information about the Particle System settings and stuff, ask me.

Comment: i read that as...  if the target is out of range, play bullet particles.  Try inverting the comparison.  Change it from `>=`  to `<=`     No change in behavior?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft I tried inverting it, the code didn't do what I wanted. If I remember properly it just completely.

Comment: Statements like `didn't do what I wanted` require clarification.  Would you mind clarifying some things?  1. What action does the code take now?  2. What action is expected?  3. What modifications to the code did you make?  4.  What were those results.   It may be a bit tedious, so thanks for taking the time.. but answering 1 and 2 directly and succinctly will help you get better results on SO.  Thanks.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft So the game I am currently making is a Tower Defense game, I will assume that you know what this are, since these are fairly popular already. This specific code checks the distance between the enemy and Tower. If the distance is less than or equal to the 'maxShootRange' value, than the Tower shoot my enemy. Now the code says if the distance is greater than or equal to the maxShootRange, than shoot. It does the exact opposite. If my maxShootRange is 30, the Towers will shoot the enemies if they are in maxShootRange. Look at the next comment for more details.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft So like I said, if the enemies are 30 blocks range from the Tower, they will shoot. Even though the code says greater or equal to, which should mean that if the enemies are further than 30 blocks, the Tower shoot at them, but its vice versa. That action is perfect, just what I wanted. Because I tried to do <= but then my enemies just stopped shooting. So I tried many things until I got to >= and it finally worked. If I tried to put an else statement which says don't shoot, but the Tower's didn't shoot at all. I did some print debugging, and it knew when it was in range.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft It knew when it was in range, but the particles just didn't seem to be coming. Perhaps there might be something wrong with the way I am calling my Particle System, because before all this range stuff it was working perfectly fine. If you need me to post the settings of my Particle System then send me a message. I will send it in about 8 hours (timezone difference).

Comment: No thanks.  May I ask what looks like a simple question?  If an enemy is 30 squares away and the tower's max range is 30, which of these two conditional if statements is satisfied? `if(distanceBetweenBoth >= maxShootRange)`  OR `if(distanceBetweenBoth <= maxShootRange)`  ?   The first one, the second one, or both?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft I assume you mean which one of these work? The >=  works, but it works vice versa. If the enemy was 30 or closer, then it starts shooting. 
I assume that you mean which one of these work? Well the >= works, but works vice versa. If the code is >= and the enemy are less than or 30 blocks away it shoots. But this doesn't matter anymore, because for some reason my code just started working.

Comment: Oh yeah, code is like that.  Sometimes 30 is greater than or equal to 30, sometimes it's not.  Who knows.  Glad you got it sorted. Wishing you the best of luck.